# Is there a way to register a BroadcastReceiver to listen for android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED with a context?

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to listen for a USB device being attached but only when my app is already open. Tutorials online register a BroadcastReceiver in the AndroidManifest file like so:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".myBroadcastReceiver"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action  android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
        android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
</receiver>
```

However from my understanding this registers the BroadcastReceiver as an entry point into the app. When the intent is sent out while the app is closed, it will instantiate the class myBroadcastReceiver and open the app. This is not behavior I want. There is another way to register a BroadcastReceiver using a context which would work much better for me that looks like this:

```
val receiver = myBroadcastReceiver()
val intentFilter = IntentFilter(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED)
context.registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter)
```

The problem is the meta-data tag in the first strategy. It seems to be necessary for the intent to be given to my BroadcastReceiver but I can't find a way to replicate it in the dynamic registration. Is there a way to add this meta data to the second code block? I would also be willing to not have the device filter at all and just receive an intent whenever any USB device is attached.